# break out each unique value of a column into multiple columns then display in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my actual data I have the following query

```
SELECT Sales Person,
        (CASE WHEN [ProductType] = 'car' THEN [GOAL_VOLUME]
          END) AS 'car Goal'
    , (CASE WHEN [ProductType] = 'boat' THEN [GOAL_VOLUME]
          END) AS 'boat Goal'
    , (CASE WHEN [ProductType] IN ('bike', 'scooter') THEN [GOAL_VOLUME]
          END) AS 'bike/scooter Goal'
FROM PRODUCT_GOALS
```

My current results are each Sales Person's name broken out 3 times into 3 rows with each row having only one non-NULL value for the Goal_Volume... I need everything on one row... Might need multiple subqueries to join against for each product?
See image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI9ld.png)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Take a look at the PIVOT documentation - sorry I don't have time to do it for you.

Comment: Are these two different questions?

Comment: `how can I roll this up so that Clothes and Entertainment are in 2 columns while each of the USR_NAME values are their own columns (so would be 8 columns in this case).` This is a bit confusing, can you show us how it should looks like ?

Comment: My apologies, updated to add image link explaining my issue and desired output. Thanks

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT [Sales Person]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN [ProductType] = 'car' THEN [GOAL_VOLUME]
          END) AS 'car Goal'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN [ProductType] = 'boat' THEN [GOAL_VOLUME]
          END) AS 'boat Goal'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN [ProductType] IN ('bike', 'scooter') THEN [GOAL_VOLUME]
          END) AS 'bike/scooter Goal'
FROM PRODUCT_GOALS
GROUP BY [Sales Person]
```

Almost the same query as yours, just added `MAX` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you! Since the GOAL_VOLUME is a static value manually inputted, MAX is a great and simple solution!

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)